# How to save the value of the button after reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In the template component `AppComponent`, depending on the value, the variable `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` switches between the `logIn()` and `logout()` methods, which in the application component `AppComponent` are subscribed to these methods in the service `LoggedinService` and depending on the method, change the value of the variable to true or false.

Also in the Guard's method `checkLogin (url: string)` I return true or false depending on the value of the variable `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn`

**Everything works, but when I reset the page, I need to keep the value of the input or output button. How to implement it?**

**template of AppComponent:**

```html
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success"
                   [class.btn-outline-success]="!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
                   [class.btn-outline-danger]="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn"
                   (click)="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? logout() : logIn()">
                    {{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn ? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
                </a>
            </li>
```

**code of AppComponent:**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private loggedInService: LoggedinService,
                private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    logIn(): void {
        this.loggedInService.login().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn) {
                let redirect = this.loggedInService.redirectUrl ? this.loggedInService.redirectUrl :
                    '/gallery';
                this.router.navigate([redirect]);
            }
        });
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.loggedInService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

**LoggedinService:**

```js
export class LoggedinService implements OnInit{
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    redirectUrl: string;
    
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    login(): Observable<boolean> {
        return of(true).pipe(
            delay(100),
            tap(val => this.isLoggedIn = true)
        );
    }

    logout(): boolean {
        return this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

**AuthGuard**:

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loggedInService: LoggedinService) {
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot):  boolean{
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.loggedInService.redirectUrl = url;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'app-root'
  }
];
```

**GalleryRoutingModule**

```js
const galleryRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'gallery',
        component: GalleryMainComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: '', component: GalleryComponent,},
            {path: 'add', component: GalleryAddComponent},
            {path: ':id', component: GalleryItemComponent},
        ]
    },
];
```

Comment: use session storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the value in `localStorage` , also you can create a service to handle set and get the value from localStorage (recommended)

example

```
localStorage.setItem('login',state);
localStorage.getItem('login'); // string value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use localStorage to retain the value of input/output

```
  afterAuthentication(){
     return localStorage.getItem('isLogged', true);
   }

   login(){
     localStorage.setItem('login', true);
   }

   logout(){
   localStorage.setItem('login', false);
   }
```

and in your ngOnit function check getItem() from locaLStorage check the condition and retain values accordingly.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` take only one parameter as key

Comment: but we can define two var and call two getItems for value check

Answer (score 0):

Since you reload the page, the state of the application gets reset. What you can do is use the localStorage to keep the value of the button and read it from there when the page loads. If there is a value use that else default to your value.